# HTTPS Delay Over VLAN

Tags: https, lan, cisco

There is 30 seconds delay when i send an HTTPS request from "PC1"
to "PC2", "PC2" located in an other "VLAN", This "VLAN" is configured using a Cisco
router. i found that the date and time of the "PC1" and "PC2" not synced.
once i configured the same date and time over these 2 PCs, the delay
disappeared. when "PC1" and "PC2" were on the same network i didn't faced this problem.

Any advice.

[Severs Date and Time](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/synchronize-a-cisco-routers-clock-with-network-time-protocol-ntp/)

Comment: set the time correctly on both machines. use http instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the UDP port 137,it was closed where the self signed certificate has a host name and use this port to resolve this host name.